# Using google maps polyline to draw bezier curve

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw a bezier curve in google maps by using a SVG path in a Polyline. At first I used a Marker instead similar to [Curved line between two near points in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321006/curved-line-between-two-near-points-in-google-maps), which gave the results that I'm after. However, since it's not possible to drag the map under the marker, I can't use this method.

So I switched to a Polyline instead of a marker. Now I get the same good results when I zoom out, but when I zoom in the curve becomes "cropped".

Here is the code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var coord1 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.165876, -123.152446);
    var coord2 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.786328, -80.193694);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(coord1);
    bounds.extend(coord2);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    pLineOpt = {
        path: [coord1, coord2],
        strokeWeight: 4,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        map: map,
    }

    pLine = new google.maps.Polyline(pLineOpt);

    var markers = [
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coord1,
            map: map
        }),
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coord2,
            map: map
        })
    ];

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        //points
        var p1 = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(coord1);
        var p2 = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(coord2);
        //distance between points
        var d = new google.maps.Point(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);
        var lengthSqr = d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y;
        //middle point
        var m = new google.maps.Point(d.x / 2, d.y / 2);
        //slope of perpendicular line
        var perpK = -d.x / d.y;
        //distance to control point
        var ratioDistanceControlLengthSqr = 9;
        var controlDSqr = lengthSqr / ratioDistanceControlLengthSqr;
        var p3dX = Math.sqrt(controlDSqr / (Math.pow(perpK, 2) + 1));
        var p3dY = perpK * p3dX;
        //control point
        var p3 = new google.maps.Point(m.x - p3dX, m.y - p3dY);
        //curve path
        var path = "M 0 0 q " + p3.x + " " + p3.y + " " + d.x + " " + d.y;
        //calc scale                
        var zoom = map.getZoom();
        var scale = 1 / (Math.pow(2, -zoom));

        var icon = {
            path: path,
            scale: scale,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            strokeOpacity: 1,
        };

        pLineOpt.icons = [{
            fixedRotation: true,
            icon: icon,
            offset: '0'
        }];
        pLine.setOptions(pLineOpt);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have made a jsfiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/s7djLzyd/3/

Does anyone know why the Polyline is cropped when zooming, and if there is a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Your polyline is being cropped at the [tile boundary](http://jsfiddle.net/s7djLzyd/4/).  Seen this happen lots of times, not sure why it is happening in your particular case, but probably a bug in the API tiled rendering of the polyline.  First thing I always suggest with weird issues is to try the release and frozen versions of the API, [that doesn't help in this case](http://jsfiddle.net/s7djLzyd/5/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your Polyline Options :

```
pLineOpt = {
    path: [coord1, coord2],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
}
```

Please try this code snippet : May be this is what you want... :)

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var coord1 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.165876, -123.152446);
    var coord2 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.786328, -80.193694);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(coord1);
    bounds.extend(coord2);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    pLineOpt = {
        path: [coord1, coord2],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4
    }

    pLine = new google.maps.Polyline(pLineOpt);

    var markers = [
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coord1,
        map: map
    }),
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coord2,
        map: map
    })];

    pLine.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {

    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From this related question: [Google Maps API: Bézier curve polyline wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529966/google-maps-api-b%c3%a9zier-curve-polyline-wrap)

```
var curvedLine = new GmapsCubicBezier(
      49.165876, -123.152446, 
      33.811192,-115.032444, 
      30.820807,-123.749998, 
      25.786328, -80.193694, 
      0.01, map);
```

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1oqab0vn/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

code snippet:

```js
var map;
var origLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(45, -85);

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.811192, -115.032444),
    zoom: 3
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  var coord1 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.165876, -123.152446);
  var coord2 = new google.maps.LatLng(25.786328, -80.193694);
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coord1,
    title: "marker 1",
    map: map
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coord2,
    title: "marker 2",
    map: map
  });


  var curvedLine = new GmapsCubicBezier(
    49.165876, -123.152446,
    33.811192, -115.032444,
    30.820807, -123.749998,
    25.786328, -80.193694,
    0.01, map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var GmapsCubicBezier = function(lat1, long1, lat2, long2, lat3, long3, lat4, long4, resolution, map) {

  var points = [];

  for (it = 0; it <= 1; it += resolution) {
    points.push(this.getBezier({
      x: lat1,
      y: long1
    }, {
      x: lat2,
      y: long2
    }, {
      x: lat3,
      y: long3
    }, {
      x: lat4,
      y: long4
    }, it));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    var Line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].x, points[i].y), new google.maps.LatLng(points[i + 1].x, points[i + 1].y, false)],
      geodesic: true,
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      /* icons: [{
          icon: {
              path: 'M 0,-2 0,2',
              strokeColor: 'violet',
              strokeOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 4
          },
          repeat: '36px'
      }, {
          icon: {
              path: 'M -1,-2 -1,2',
              strokeColor: 'black',
              strokeOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 2
          },
          repeat: '36px'
      }] */
    });
    Line.setMap(map);
  }
  // connect end of line to first point
  var Line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [new google.maps.LatLng(lat1,long1),new google.maps.LatLng(points[points.length-1].x, points[points.length-1].y)],
      geodesic: true,
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      /* icons: [{
          icon: {
              path: 'M 0,-2 0,2',
              strokeColor: 'violet',
              strokeOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 4
          },
          repeat: '36px'
      }, {
          icon: {
              path: 'M -1,-2 -1,2',
              strokeColor: 'black',
              strokeOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 2
          },
          repeat: '36px'
      }] */
    });
    Line.setMap(map);
  
  return Line;
};


GmapsCubicBezier.prototype = {

  B1: function(t) {
    return t * t * t;
  },
  B2: function(t) {
    return 3 * t * t * (1 - t);
  },
  B3: function(t) {
    return 3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t);
  },
  B4: function(t) {
    return (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t);
  },
  getBezier: function(C1, C2, C3, C4, percent) {
    var pos = {};
    pos.x = C1.x * this.B1(percent) + C2.x * this.B2(percent) + C3.x * this.B3(percent) + C4.x * this.B4(percent);
    pos.y = C1.y * this.B1(percent) + C2.y * this.B2(percent) + C3.y * this.B3(percent) + C4.y * this.B4(percent);
    return pos;
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```