# Google Maps API V3 - DirectionsService

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there the option to add the "dashed/dotted" line from the marker to the start of the route in the google maps API V3?

[image: google maps direction service]

The red marker in the right part of the image represents the current location, but the route always starts from the street and I could not find the option to add the missing connection - or do I miss something else?

```
directionsService.route({
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC ,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a dashed curved polyline in Google Maps JS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131378/how-to-make-a-dashed-curved-polyline-in-google-maps-js-api)

Comment: The mentioned link is focusing more on how to draw a dashed line rather than to solve the issue with the directions service: I set the starting point (current location) through "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition",  but the directionservice sets another pin on the street where the route is starting from - best M

Comment: Directions service and directions renderer in the API don't implement this feature, so to get the similar behavior as in maps.google.com you have to implement it yourself.