# How to install google maps through npm in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

Is there any package available on npm for google maps in react native.
I want to use the google.maps.Bounds, google.maps.Point, google.maps.LatLngBounds, google.maps.Marker, google.maps.LatLng, to enable me draw a curved polyline in react native maps as seen in the image below and as described in [How to make a dashed curved polyline in Google Maps JS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131378/how-to-make-a-dashed-curved-polyline-in-google-maps-js-api).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found this `react-native-maps` [library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) that can be installed through npm. The library includes different Google Maps APIs components such as, [Map View](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md), [Markers](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md), [Polyline](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polyline.md) and [more](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps#component-api).

To get you started with this, you can check the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks... I already got what I was looking for. The react native maps dint have the geometry library