# Drawing a smooth polyline on google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I am using googlemaps api to draw Polyline between coordinates(Lat/Lang) obtained from a GPS device using Angular 6. The coordinates are being updated with an interval of 10-seconds. I am using google maps's Polyline class to draw the line but the problem is that every time it draws line between the two points( new point and old point), it instantly jumps between the points instead of doing an Uber-like smooth animated path drawing. I need a smooth path drawing between points.

I'm readingcoordinates from a JSON file for the time being..

Can anybody help me out with this.?

Here is the code to draw Polyline:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import { } from 'googlemaps'
// import { } from '@types/googlemaps'
import { DataFetcherService } from "src/app/services/data-fetcher.service";

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, from } from "rxjs";
import { Promise } from "q";
// import {} fr

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'maps-app';
  @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;
  snappedPolyline: google.maps.Polyline;
  icon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png";
  private snappedCoordinates: any[] = [];
  index = 1;
  markerOffset = 0;
  prevMarkerOffset = 0;
  prevlatlng;
  latlng;
  ngOnInit() {

      this.initMap()

     // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
      // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
      var lineSymbol = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 8,
        strokeColor: '#393'
      };

    this.snappedPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: this.snappedCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        icons: [{
          icon : lineSymbol,
          offset: '100%'
        }],
        map: this.map
      })
      this.setCenter();
  }
   constructor (private dataFetcher: DataFetcherService){ }
  initMap(){
    let mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(8.89443000002,76.61418),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(){

    console.log("After content init")
    this.dataFetcher.fetchJSONData('assets/data/latlangobj.json').subscribe(data => {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(8.89443000002,76.61418),
        map: this.map,
        icon: this.icon,
        title: 'Center !'
      });

      data.forEach((cordinates) => {

        setTimeout(() =>
        {       
          console.log("setTimeout(), this.index * 12000 :", this.index * 12000)
          this.prevlatlng = this.latlng          
          this.latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(cordinates.lat, cordinates.lng)
          this.snappedPolyline.getPath().push(this.latlng);
          this.prevlatlng = this.latlng
          this.snappedPolyline.setMap(this.map);
          this.updateMarkerPosition(this.map, marker, cordinates.lat, cordinates.lng);
        }, this.index * 500);  // 6k *  this.index
        ++this.index
      });  
      }, // outer-observable ends here
     err => console.error(err)
    )
  }

  calculateDistances(start, end) {

    var stuDistances = {};
    const metres = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(start, end);    // distance in metres
        return metres
    }

      // update marker position
      updateMarkerPosition(map, marker, lat, lon) {
          console.log("MoveMarker()")
          try {
          marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon));
          map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon));
        } catch (e) {}
      }
    // set the center to the updated latlang
  setCenter() {
    this.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(8.89443000002,76.61418));

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(8.89443000002,76.61418),
      map: this.map,
      icon: this.icon,
      title: 'Center !'
    });
}
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810345/using-google-maps-polyline-to-draw-bezier-curve

Comment: can u clarify how is it similar to the link u pointed. I am asking to smoothly update my marker drawing a polyline as the data comes in from a GPS device. I do not need any specific design for curve, instead, i need an animated (smooth) path drawn as polyline on map as the device moves on.

Comment: @UsmanAhmad have u found any solution to this?